# How to detect 3rd party app details on experience portal login page?

Tags: lightning-experience, connected-apps, encoding

I have different 3rd party applications that uses Salesforce Connected app to login to their application where Salesforce is OAuth.

I have added those application details on my Experience portal page where can directly navigate to the site and I configured URL in backend like this:

URL:

https://myapp.force.com/portal/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=some_client_Id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fuat.3rdpartyapp.com%2Fsignin-salesforce&

If I hit above URL directly, it displays Experience portal login page where by using SF credential, user can login & navigate to 3rd party applications and it automatically encodes the URL which I am not sure which encoding technique it uses but encoded URL is like this:

[https://myapp.site.com/portal/s/login/?language=en_US&ec=302&inst=3H&startURL=%2Fportal%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DSAFASFSAFCXZCZCXZCXZCZSFWEWREWRCZXCXZVZXVZXVXZVFWFRQAXzCXZFSAD"](https://myapp.site.com/portal/s/login/?language=en_US&ec=302&inst=3H&startURL=%2Fportal%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DSAFASFSAFCXZCZCXZCXZCZSFWEWREWRCZXCXZVZXVZXVXZVFWFRQAXzCXZFSAD%22)

We have different different applications with different URL which uses Salesforce as OAuth.

When user hit 3rd party application URL which asks for login and navigate to Experience portal  page, I want to somhow detect on Experience portal login page which 3rd party application user is trying to login. How can I detect the same?

In Source of above encoded URL it encodes something which I want to decode here but I tried different ways where I am not able to decode whatever is the string in Sourcecode.

I also tried to create LWC on login page where to check if decoding is possible or not

```
let previousURL = document.referrer; // When it navigates to the experience portal login from 3rd party. I tried to check if it detects previous URL.
       
console.log('Decode Login Page:'+ decodeURI(previousURL));
```

Can someone please help how can I detect 3rd party application details who is trying to login to experience portal page?